# how to create a function to be used on a html link

Tags: php, mysql, function

hi i have a datatable which will fetch data from my database and will show it in my table but with the datatable i am creating two action links  one is for edit and the other is for delete 
and i have created a function for delete and now i want to use it in my delete link i tried using it but it delete all my records when i try to use it
here is my code

```
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td align='center'>$row[name]</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>$row[add1]</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>$row[city]</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>$row[tel]</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>$row[mobile1]</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>$row[contpers1]</td>";
            echo "<td><a href=\"cutomer.php?mode=false?code=$row[accode]?mode=false\"><img src='images/edit.png'></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='?delete' onClick=\"return confirm('Confrim Delete?');\"><img src='images/delete.png'></a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            if (isset($_GET["delete"])) {
               delete($zdb, "accmast", "accode", $row["accode"], "custmain.php");
                }
             }
```

here is my  function

```
function delete($mydb, $table, $vouch, $chk, $file){
    mysql_select_db($mydb);


   $qry= mysql_query("DELETE FROM $table WHERE $vouch='$chk'") or die(mysql_error());
    header("refresh: 1; $file");
}
```

Comment: You are misusing/abusing the `echo` function. You know, you can use it only once

Comment: @PHPfan - That is new information to me, can you cite that in the PHP documentation?

Comment: I think PHPfan is saying that he only HAS to use it once, not multiple times.

Comment: You can't directly run a PHP function using a Javascript onclick call. You'd have to set up an ajax function that calls a page that will run that function. Or link directly to a delete page that redirects once the delete is complete.

Comment: My mistake, I see that now.

Comment: putting array in an echo without curlies { } `echo "..code=$row[accode]?mo..";` eugh!! http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php see Complex (curly) syntax

Comment: @user2274075: This doesn't answer your question, but [please read this](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you are asking if delete is set inside de while stament, and, of course delete all the records.

Try with the if outside and before the while, and you need also a id of the record you want to delete for example in the "delete" from the GET vars:

```
        if (isset($_GET["delete"])) {
           delete($zdb, "accmast", "accode", $_GET["delete"], "custmain.php");
        }
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td align='center'>$row[name]</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>$row[add1]</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>$row[city]</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>$row[tel]</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>$row[mobile1]</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>$row[contpers1]</td>";
            echo "<td><a href=\"cutomer.php?mode=false?code=$row[accode]?mode=false\"><img src='images/edit.png'></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='?delete' onClick=\"return confirm('Confrim Delete?');\"><img src='images/delete.png'></a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
```

Comment: but how will i get the code related to the record i want to delete??

Comment: Your link to delete a record needs a param delete with the ID of record to delete. Like this: <a href="?delete=#id_number#">delete</a>

Answer (score 0):

You should echo the statement

```
"DELETE FROM $table WHERE $vouch='$chk'"
```

and see what it get in WHERE condition. If it deletes all rows, the problem should be here.

And I'm not 100% sure, but $row[accode] should be replaced to {$row['accode']} in that string

Comment: and comment out the `mysql_query` so it doesn't do it while you debug

Comment: @Waygood I thought it's rather obvious so I skipped that part :)

Answer (score 0):

In the mysql_query()

"DELETE FROM $table WHERE $vouch='$chk'"

should be

"DELETE FROM $table WHERE $vouch='" . $chk. "'"

Comment: Doesn't need to be. But you should also do $table and $vouch and suggest using `mysql_real_escape_string()`